# Show values in grid according to a combobox selected value

Tags: peoplesoft

I have a combobox, on which I have to choose one option. That option determines which values should be shown on the comboboxes of a grid. The values to show on the grid's comboboxes are on a table. Right now, I'm showing all of them, but I need to filter it down.

The user must choose a value on combobox #1, and the comboboxes inside the grid (#2) should only show the related values. So far, I haven't been able to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Page]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refresh your drop down list as follows:

```
&l_field.ClearDropDownList();

/* select values required by sql */   
&l_sql = CreateSql("...");

While &l_sql.Fetch(&l_key, &l_descr)
   &l_field.AddDropDownItem(&l_key, &l_descr);
End-While;
```